# How to pass xml data from php to flash

Tags: php, xml, flash

How can I pass xml data from php to flash, without using xml file?

Comment: [AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/)

Comment: [Zend_Amf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.html) is the library officially supported by Adobe.
Also check the [Adobe Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex_php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same loading method in actionscript, just point it to a php script instead.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo "<xml_nodes></xml_nodes>";
```